# How to change the ForEach method into a break-able one/surpass the 6 minute limit on Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, foreach

On Apps Script there is a 6 minute limit on execution time, and since i have a ton of data to go through, i'm trying to avoid this problem.

```
function myPositions(security, actions, quantity, price){
  let portfolio = generateFifo(security, actions, quantity, price);
  let returnArray = [];
  portfolio.forEach((value, key) => {

    let shares = 0;
    let totalCost = 0;
    let avgPrice = 0;

    value.map(trade => {
      shares += trade.shares;
      totalCost += trade.shares * trade.price;
    });

    avgPrice = totalCost / shares;
    returnArray.push([key, shares, avgPrice]);
  });
  return returnArray;
}
```

this is the fuction that i need to run

```
function generateFifo(security, actions, quantity, price){
  let portfolio = new Map();
  for(var i=0; i<security.length; i++){
    let ticker = security[i].toString();
    let action = actions[i].toString();
    let stockQuant = Number(quantity[i]);
    let stockPrice = Number(price[i]);

    let trade = generateTrade(stockQuant, stockPrice, action);

    if(action == "Buy" || action.toUpperCase() == "DRIP"){
      let activeTrades = portfolio.get(ticker);

      if(activeTrades == null){
        portfolio.set(ticker, [trade]);
      }
      else {
        activeTrades.push(trade);
      }
    }

    if(action == "Sell"){
      let activeTrades = portfolio.get(ticker);
      let precision = 5; //numero di cifre decimali

      if(activeTrades != null){
        let sharesToSell = Number(Number(trade.shares).toFixed(precision));
        while(sharesToSell > 0){
          sharesToSell = Number(Number(sharesToSell).toFixed(precision));

          if(activeTrades.length > 0){
            let itemToSell = activeTrades[0];
            itemToSell.shares = Number(Number(itemToSell.shares).toFixed(precision));

            if(itemToSell.shares == sharesToSell){
              sharesToSell = 0;
              activeTrades.splice(0,1);
            }

            else if(itemToSell.shares < sharesToSell){
              sharesToSell -= itemToSell.shares;
              activeTrades.splice(0,1);
            }

            else{
              itemToSell.shares -= sharesToSell;
              sharesToSell = 0;
            }
          }
        }

        if(activeTrades.length == 0){
          portfolio.delete(ticker);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return portfolio;
}
```

```
function generateTrade(stockQuant, stockPrice, action){
  return {
    shares: stockQuant,
    price: stockPrice,
    action: action
  };
}
```

and these are the other called functions.

While i have found some code online that i could implement in mine to help me surpass the 6 minute limit of Google Scripts.

```
function testSolution() {
  
  var start = (new Date()).getTime(); // tempo di avvio dello script
  const MAX_RUNNING_TIME = 300000; // 5 minuti (limite di esecuzione manuale, per stare entro i 6 minuti)
  const TIME_TO_WAIT_FOR_TRIGGER_ATTIVATION = 120000; // 2 minuti (tempo di attivazione del trigger)
  var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache(); // inizializza la cache per gestire l'ultima iterazione
  var cached_i = cache.get("last_i"); // recupera dalla cache l'eventuale ultimo valore di iterazione
  if (cached_i == null) { cached_i = 1; } // se non c'è un'iterazione la inizializza
  var max_cells = 30; // numero massimo di iterazioni (cicli) impostato
  for (i=cached_i; i<=max_cells; i++) { // effettua n cicli dal valore dell'ultima iterazione fino al massimo indicato
    var lap = (new Date()).getTime(); // tempo di esecuzione dello script ad ogni ciclo
    if(lap - start >= MAX_RUNNING_TIME) { // se la differenza tra il tempo di inizio e quello attuale supera i 5 minuti impostati
      cache.put("last_i", i, 1800); // salva il valore dell'attuale iterazione in cache per 30 minuti
      // crea un trigger basato sul tempo con data e ora specifica (momento attuale + 2 minuti) per rieseguire la funzione
      ScriptApp.newTrigger("testSolution").timeBased().at(new Date(lap+TIME_TO_WAIT_FOR_TRIGGER_ATTIVATION)).create();
      break; // esce dal loop
    } else { // se la differenza tra il tempo di inizio e quello attuale è inferiore ai 5 minuti impostati
      // svolge le operazioni effettive dello script
      // INSERIRE QUI LE OPERAZIONI DELLO SCRIPT
    }
  }
  if (i >= max_cells) { cache.remove('last_i'); } // se il numero i cicli totali è stato raggiunto pulisce la cache
}
```

i have the problem that i'd need to implement pieces of it inside the ForEach loop in the myPositions function, and i can't do a break from inside it.

Do you know another way to implement it, or someway to altogether replace the ForEach loop with a breakable one?

thanks in andvance and sorry for the poor explanation.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. We already have several question abouts how to handle the Google Apps Script execution time limit. Please spend some time searching this site. If you still need help, please add a [mcve] (less code, more relevant details, like a brief description of the source data, the expected result, and what the 'mcve' does)

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to break out of an Array.forEach() use Array.some() instead.

If the return value of the callback function is false it will continue with the next iteration.  If true it stops.

```
function test() {
  try {
    let a = [];
    let b = [1,2,3,4,5];
    b.some( value => {
        if( value < 4 ) {
          a.push(value*10);
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      }
    );
    console.log(a);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Execution log

```
2:37:09 PM  Notice  Execution started
2:37:10 PM  Info    [ 10, 20, 30 ]
2:37:10 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Reference

- [Array.som()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_some.asp)